# Komodo IDE wont see my Python Modules

Tags: python, macos, ide, terminal, komodo

I hope it is just that I am doing something stupid but for some reason Komodo wont see a modules I have on my machine. I used PIP to install paramiko and it installed fine. From a terminal the builtin python and ipython will see and import the module fine. When I am trying to write a Python script and I try to import paramiko, Komodo thins its not there at all. I am not sure what to do to fix this.

I did instal some other items from pip and Komodo sees them right away but for what ever reason it wont see paramiko. I will try this on Windwos and Linux to make sure its not just my setup. I hope someone can help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Komodo editor under Linux, so I hope I am not pointing you to a place that does not exist in the IDE, but I hardly doubt it.

So, have you tried adding the module in Komodo:

preferences --> languages --> python --> additional python import directories

This might work.

Answer (score 0):

Joren basically got it  but I added the entire "site-packages" folder to Edit (Komodo on OS X) > Preferences > Languages > Python: Additional Python Import Directories, reason being that I hit the issue with other modules.

You shouldn't need to do that obviously.  There is a bug filed and it should be fixed soon: http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=99829